# check whether two circle touch each other externally and only at one point

Tags: python, class, geometry

i need to find out whether two circles which are c1 and c2 touch each other externally and at only one point by using Circle class.
I created method which is touches. The method should return a boolean value and it needs to be called like this c1.touches(c2)

this formula to check circles touch or intersect with each other [formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uE87i.png)

this is my code

```
import math

class Circle:

    def __init__(self, x, y, r):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.r = r

    def touches(self):

        dist_between_centers = math.sqrt((self.c1.x - self.c2.x)^(2 + (self.c1.y - self.c2.y)^2))
        if dist_between_centers == (self.c1.r + self.c2.r):
            print("True")
        elif dist_between_centers > (self.c1.r + self.c2.r):
            print("False")
        else:
            print("False")


c1 = Circle(2,3,12)
c2 = Circle(15, 28, 10)
c1.touches(c2)
```

However i am getting error like this, TypeError: touches() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: `touches` doesn't take an argument (other than the class `self`), but you call it with one: `c1.touches(c2)`

Comment: when i called it c1.touches(c2) i am getting type error     c1.touches(c2)
TypeError: touches() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: Something is wrong with the code you pasted. If you call `touches ` as `c1.touches(c2)`, it's quite strange that you're accessing `self.c1` and `self.c2` inside `touches`. Please look more carefully and fix it.

Comment: You shoudl read what `self` means in a class function, and why your `c2` argument is actually the 2nd argument.

Comment: Note that since we're not checking for intersection there's no need for the second check, it touches or it doesn't. And it should probably return [boolean `True` and `False`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_booleans.asp) not the strings `"True"` and `"False"`.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you mix up with usage `self`, `c1` and `c2` in `def touches`

You should pass `c2` as parameter to `def touches(circle)`. Inside method you should refer the first circle as `self` rather `self.c1` and the second as `circle` rather than `self.c2`

Final code like this

```
import math

class Circle:

    def __init__(self, x, y, r):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.r = r

    def touches(self, circle):

        dist_between_centers = math.sqrt((self.x - circle.x)^2 + (self.y - circle.y)^2)
        if dist_between_centers == (self.r + circle.r):
            print("True")
        elif dist_between_centers > (self.r + circle.r):
            print("False")
        else:
            print("False")


c1 = Circle(2, 3, 12)
c2 = Circle(15, 28, 10)
c1.touches(c2)
```

Comment: @Schwern sure. I tried to keep code as much similar to OP's as possible